# Is there a way to clone my student ID card with an Android phone? (MIFARE DESfire)

Tags: android, rfid, mifare

Is there any way to clone my Student ID card for use with my Android Phone? I found an app for cloning MIFARE Classic cards, but it shows my card as a DESFIRE [image]

I realize it's exactly the sort of thing the system is supposed to protect against, but I have no malicious intent! I just want to simplify the daily contents of my pockets.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a student card or that you don't have malicious intent. Your question boils down to "can I clone a mifare desfire card?" And you have already said that it is designed to prevent that.

Comment: Yes fair enough. I added those details just for some context. So the answer is no?

Comment: The answer is "yes" if you can break the encryption.

Comment: I appreciate your response thank you.